# How to disable an option when selected more than 5 times in dynamically generated rows?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, jquery-ui-multiselect

Following is my code :

```
<tr class = "dynamicRow">
    <td class="dynamicStu"><b><bean:message key="label.student.code" />:</b>
                                        </td><td >
                                         <logic:present name="studentList">
                                            <html:select property="dgList[0].stuCreate"
                                            styleId="stuselect" onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
                                                <html:option value="">
                                                    <bean:message key="label.student.code" />
                                                </html:option>
                                                <html:optionsCollection name="masStudentForm"
                                                    property="studentList" label="label" value="value" />
                                            </html:select>
                                        </logic:present> 
                                            </td>
                                        </div>
....
</tr>
```

At the end of the row I have an add button where this dropdown will be added dynamically.Along with this dropdown many other textfields are present.

My Requirement : When user selects the same option in the dropdown the valuesmore than 5 times the values should get disabled. Should happen on Onchange() of this dropdown. Kindly help.

Comment: So there are mutliple such dropdown in your `trs` and you want if the same value is selected more then 5 times in any of the `trs` disable that option am i right or can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: 1. The whole <tr> contains this dropdown only once and some textFields.     2.  This <tr> can be added dynamically.  3. Requirement is when user selects the same option in the dropdown more than 5 times in any of the dynamically added <tr>s then alert to be thrown or the value to be disabled.

Comment: I have tried using the conventional method of putting the dynamically added values into an array and when it exceeds 5 throwing alert. Is there any other easier way to do this? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get value of your selects using `.val()` then you need to *iterate* through all selects in your tables to see how many ***times*** that value is selected . If the value matches then ***increment*** the count and at the end you can check if the count value is `> 5` then show *alert* or *disable* that option.

***Demo Code*** ( with dummy datas) :

```js
function setStudentLimit(el) {
  var intKeyCount = 0;
  var value = $(el).val(); //get that value
  //iterate through all selects
  $('.dynamicRow select').each(function() {
    //if value matches
    if ($(this).val() === value) {
      intKeyCount++; //increment
    }
  }); 
  if (intKeyCount > 5) {
    alert("you cannot choose again");
    //or disable that option
    //$(el).find("option:selected").prop('disabled',true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Selects</th>
 </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr class="dynamicRow">

    <td>
      <select onchange="setStudentLimit(this);">
        <option value="">--Select---</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```